# Rolling Standard Deviation of past n days (weekday vs week-end)

Tags: python, pandas, date, rolling-computation

I have a df as follows:

```
Date       Day of Week Value
01/02/2022 Sunday      35666
01/03/2022 Monday      38945
01/04/2022 Tuesday     39411
01/05/2022 Wednesday   40058
```

Essentially, I would like to be computing Averages of Values based on weekday (Monday to Friday) versus week-end (Saturday to Sunday) and their respecting Standard Deviations.

I have been trying to use group by and rolling averages, but I am not sure how to be doing this to establish a limit of past n days (say, 3 months/quarter).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why do you think that you need a `rolling`? Please extend your example to show more months if relevant and provide the matching expected output.

Answer (score 0):

The **first thing** to do when you work with **time data** is to change the column type to **`datetime`** with [`pandas.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html). Then you can create a new column to indicate if the day is on the weekend :

```py
df["is_weekend"] = df["Date"].apply(lambda row: 0 if row.day_of_week in range(0, 5) else 1)
```

With this new column, you can use [`pandas.DataFrame.rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) with [`pandas.DataFrame.mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html) and [`pandas.DataFrame.std`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.std.html)

Comment: Thank you @Pierre-Loic, this has been quite helpful.

After revisiting my project, I have grouped my dataframe on quarter/weekday vs week-end.

Now, if want to return only values that are above the mean for quarter/weekday vs week-end, I use this:

means = df.groupby(['quarter','is_weekend'])['value'].transform('mean')

df[df['value'] > means]

but I am curious if there is a way for me to return only values that are 1 or 2 standard deviations above the mean of this column 'value'?

Comment: You can create a function to calculate the z-score (or use the function `scipy.stats.zscore` https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.zscore.html) and use it in the transform method to select only 1 or 2 standard deviations from the mean